# Comando de loop para agrupar valores de um banco de dados em uma nova lista

Tags: r, loop

Boa tarde pessoal!

Estou iniciando no R (bem iniciando mesmo) e tentei fazer um script para resolver uma operação simples que, porém, foi realizada inteiramente no excel durante um minicurso que fiz, dando um grande trabalho.

o objetivo do script é ler os dados de uma tabela em que constam uma série história dos dados de precipitação (1974-2018) e calcular o desvio padrão apenas para os eventos considerandos dentro de um intervalo (50mm até 300mm).

Consegui elaborar o script e chegar no resultado esperado, porém, gostaria de saber como usar um comando de loop para armazenar os dados de precipatação do intervalo esperado sem a necessidade de ter 30 linhas para isso.

Abaixo segue o script elaborado:

```
## importação dos dados
teste <- read.table("serie.txt", h=T, sep=";")
## apresentação de parte dos dados
teste [1:12, 1:10]
## definição do limite mínimo de precipitação
def.min <- 50
## definição do limite máximo de precipitação
def.max <- 300
## agrupamento dos episódios com precipitação entre 50 mm e 300 mm para cada dia
filtro.dia1 <- teste[teste$Dia1 >= def.min & teste$Dia1 < def.max ,]
filtro.dia2 <- teste[teste$Dia2 >= def.min & teste$Dia2< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia3 <- teste[teste$Dia3 >= def.min & teste$Dia3< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia4 <- teste[teste$Dia4 >= def.min & teste$Dia4< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia5 <- teste[teste$Dia5 >= def.min & teste$Dia5< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia6 <- teste[teste$Dia6 >= def.min & teste$Dia6< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia7 <- teste[teste$Dia7 >= def.min & teste$Dia7< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia8 <- teste[teste$Dia8 >= def.min & teste$Dia8< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia9 <- teste[teste$Dia9 >= def.min & teste$Dia9< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia10 <- teste[teste$Dia10 >= def.min & teste$Dia10< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia11 <- teste[teste$Dia11 >= def.min & teste$Dia11< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia12 <- teste[teste$Dia12 >= def.min & teste$Dia12< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia13 <- teste[teste$Dia13 >= def.min & teste$Dia13< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia14 <- teste[teste$Dia14 >= def.min & teste$Dia14< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia15 <- teste[teste$Dia15 >= def.min & teste$Dia15< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia16 <- teste[teste$Dia16 >= def.min & teste$Dia16< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia17 <- teste[teste$Dia17 >= def.min & teste$Dia17< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia18 <- teste[teste$Dia18 >= def.min & teste$Dia18< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia19 <- teste[teste$Dia19 >= def.min & teste$Dia19< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia20 <- teste[teste$Dia20 >= def.min & teste$Dia20< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia21 <- teste[teste$Dia21 >= def.min & teste$Dia21< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia22 <- teste[teste$Dia22 >= def.min & teste$Dia22< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia23 <- teste[teste$Dia23 >= def.min & teste$Dia23< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia24 <- teste[teste$Dia24 >= def.min & teste$Dia24< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia25 <- teste[teste$Dia25 >= def.min & teste$Dia25< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia26 <- teste[teste$Dia26 >= def.min & teste$Dia26< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia27 <- teste[teste$Dia27 >= def.min & teste$Dia27< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia28 <- teste[teste$Dia28 >= def.min & teste$Dia28< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia29 <- teste[teste$Dia29 >= def.min & teste$Dia29< def.max ,] 
filtro.dia30 <- teste[teste$Dia30 >= def.min & teste$Dia30 < def.max,]
filtro.dia31 <- teste[teste$Dia31 >= def.min & teste$Dia31 < def.max ,] 
## apresentação de todos os episódios com precipitação entre 50 mm e 300 mm
c(filtro.dia1$Dia1 , filtro.dia2$Dia2 , filtro.dia3$Dia3 , filtro.dia4$Dia4 , filtro.dia5$Dia5 , filtro.dia6$Dia6 , filtro.dia7$Dia7 , filtro.dia8$Dia8 , filtro.dia9$Dia9 , filtro.dia10$Dia10 , filtro.dia11$Dia11 , filtro.dia12$Dia12 , filtro.dia13$Dia13 , filtro.dia14$Dia14 , filtro.dia15$Dia15 , filtro.dia16$Dia16 , filtro.dia17$Dia17 , filtro.dia18$Dia18 , filtro.dia19$Dia19 , filtro.dia20$Dia20 , filtro.dia21$Dia21 , filtro.dia22$Dia22 , filtro.dia23$Dia23 , filtro.dia24$Dia24 , filtro.dia25$Dia25 , filtro.dia26$Dia26 , filtro.dia27$Dia27 , filtro.dia28$Dia28 , filtro.dia29$Dia29 , filtro.dia30$Dia30, filtro.dia31$Dia31)
## desvio padrão para os valores de precipitação entre 50 mm e 300 mm
dp.dias <- sd(c(filtro.dia1$Dia1 , filtro.dia2$Dia2 , filtro.dia3$Dia3 , filtro.dia4$Dia4 , filtro.dia5$Dia5 , filtro.dia6$Dia6 , filtro.dia7$Dia7 , filtro.dia8$Dia8 , filtro.dia9$Dia9 , filtro.dia10$Dia10 , filtro.dia11$Dia11 , filtro.dia12$Dia12 , filtro.dia13$Dia13 , filtro.dia14$Dia14 , filtro.dia15$Dia15 , filtro.dia16$Dia16 , filtro.dia17$Dia17 , filtro.dia18$Dia18 , filtro.dia19$Dia19 , filtro.dia20$Dia20 , filtro.dia21$Dia21 , filtro.dia22$Dia22 , filtro.dia23$Dia23 , filtro.dia24$Dia24 , filtro.dia25$Dia25 , filtro.dia26$Dia26 , filtro.dia27$Dia27 , filtro.dia28$Dia28 ,filtro.dia29$Dia29 , filtro.dia30$Dia30 , filtro.dia31$Dia31))
dp.dias
```

Fiz também uma tentativa de loop usando o while, mas não deu certo, retornando a mensagem "Error: object 'filtro.dia' not found". O script é o seguinte:

```
teste <- read.table("serie.txt", h=T, sep=";")
teste [1:12, 1:10]
def.min <- 50
def.max <- 300
while (i <= 31) {
    filtro.dia[i] <- teste[teste$Dia[i] >= def.min & teste$Dia[i] < def.max ,]
    filtro.dia[i]$Dia[i]
    i <- i + 1
  }
```

Segue também um exemplo da tabela que está sendo utilizada de base:

```
> teste [1:100, 1:12]
   Municipios Postos  Latitude Longitude Anos Meses Total Dia1 Dia2 Dia3 Dia4 Dia5
1      Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974     1 151.5  0.0    0    0    0    0
2      Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974     2 167.0 21.0    0   15    0    0
3      Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974     3 336.0  0.0    0    0    5    0
4      Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974     4 244.0  5.5    7    0    0    0
5      Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974     5 447.5  0.0    0   15   16    0
6      Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974     6  82.0 25.0    0    0   15    0
7      Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974     7   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
8      Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974     8   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
9      Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974     9   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
10     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974    10   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
11     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974    11   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
12     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1974    12  15.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
13     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975     1  39.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
14     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975     2 247.0  0.0   24    0   16    0
15     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975     3 367.6 10.0   11    0   33   65
16     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975     4 157.0  0.0    0    0    0   10
17     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975     5 219.0 12.0   13   16    0    0
18     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975     6  23.5  4.0    0    0    5    0
19     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975     7   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
20     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975     8   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
21     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975     9   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
22     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975    10   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
23     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975    11   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
24     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1975    12  55.0  0.0    0    0    6   49
25     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976     1  16.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
26     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976     2 151.0  0.0    0    0   10    3
27     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976     3 242.5  0.0    0    0    5    0
28     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976     4 195.0 37.0   37    0    0    1
29     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976     5  35.0  0.0    0    0    0   25
30     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976     6   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
31     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976     7   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
32     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976     8   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
33     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976     9   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
34     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976    10   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
35     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976    11   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
36     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1976    12   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
37     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977     1 166.0  0.0    0    0    0   27
38     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977     2 184.0 50.0   13    0   12    0
39     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977     3 169.0  0.0   10    0    8    0
40     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977     4 111.0  7.0    0   15    0    0
41     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977     5 129.0  0.0   11   26    0   44
42     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977     6  73.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
43     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977     7  12.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
44     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977     8   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
45     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977     9   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
46     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977    10   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
47     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977    11   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
48     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1977    12   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
49     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978     1  66.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
50     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978     2 132.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
51     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978     3  90.0  0.0    0    0    0    4
52     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978     4 160.0  0.0   28    0    0    0
53     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978     5 208.0 67.0   18    6    5    0
54     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978     6   3.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
55     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978     7  22.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
56     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978     8   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
57     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978     9   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
58     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978    10   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
59     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978    11   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
60     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1978    12   5.0  0.0    0    0    0    2
61     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979     1  68.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
62     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979     2  80.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
63     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979     3 173.0 32.0    0   37    0    0
64     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979     4 180.0  0.0    0    0    4    0
65     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979     5 100.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
66     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979     6   7.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
67     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979     7   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
68     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979     8   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
69     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979     9   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
70     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979    10   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
71     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979    11   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
72     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1979    12   9.9  0.0    0    0    0    0
73     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980     1  48.0  0.0    0    0    5    0
74     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980     2 291.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
75     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980     3 160.0  0.0    0    4    0   20
76     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980     4  60.0  0.0    0    0    0    8
77     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980     5  14.0  0.0    0    7    4    0
78     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980     6   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
79     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980     7   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
80     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980     8   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
81     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980     9   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
82     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980    10   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
83     Sobral SOBRAL -3.660639 -40.34489 1980    11   0.0  0.0    0    0    0    0
```

Desde já, agradeço pela atenção!

Comment: Quer agrupar por `Municipios`, `Postos`, `Ano`, `Mês`, ou nada? Só o desvio padrão para todos os `Dia*` no intervalo considerado?

Comment: À princípio, é apenas calcular o desvio padrão para todos os dias da tabela que estejam dentro do intervalo considerado.

Comment: Feito, veja se é isto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que o seguinte faz o que a pergunta pede.

Explicação:

1. A função primeiro determina quais as colunas de interesse com `grep`.
2. Depois usa `lapply` para ir a cada vetor coluna e ficar só com os valores que cumprem o critério de estarem entre `Min` e `Max`.
3. Finalmente, calcula o desvio padrão.

Note-se que para calcular o DP é necessário primeiro `unlist`.

```
DesvPadrao <- function(DF, colPattern = "Dia", Min, Max, na.rm = FALSE){
  icol <- grep(colPattern, names(DF))
  y <- lapply(DF[icol], function(x){
    x[Min <= x & x <= Max]
  })
  sd(unlist(y), na.rm = na.rm)
}

def.min <- 50
def.max <- 300

DesvPadrao(teste, Min = def.min, Max = def.max)
#[1] 9.291573
```

Comment: Exatamente isso!

E vi que preciso estudar bem mais a partir da resolução do problema e da sua explicação!

Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela atenção!